# How to return an object when using GROUP BY in HQL?

Tags: java, orm, hql

I have a table of messages where where I have the columns `ID`, `FROM_ID`, `TO_ID`, `DATE`, and `MESSAGE`, with usual entity bean defined. I am trying to write a query where, given a recipient (aka `TO_ID`) return the most recent message from each user (ie for each unique `FROM_ID`, return the record with the greatest `DATE`).

The query I came up with is:

```
SELECT                           
   m.id, m.fromId, m.toId, m.message, max(m.sharedDate),
FROM                             
   Messages m                       
WHERE                            
   m.toId = ?           
GROUP BY                         
   m.fromId
```

Now, I can take those columns back and populate a bean with them, but is there a way to have Hibernate do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the selected columns in a constructor call:

```
select new WrapperBean(m.id, m.fromId, m.toId, m.message, max(m.sharedDate))...
```

where WrapperBean has a constructor with those args.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that in my real situation (ie instead of the simplified version presented in the question) there are two different classes (that share a base class) that get persisted to that table and the results could have been either

Comment: there may be some slick way to do it, but a manual technique would be to include the discriminator column (or some other value that will distinguish between the types), and iterate over the Object[] yourself, and create the correct type based on that value.

Comment: is there a way to refer to a discriminator column if it doesn't get mapped to any of the entity beans? Apparently, there is: `The special property class accesses the discriminator value of an instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator value.` Like `from Cat cat where cat.class = DomesticCat`

Comment: if Messages is your super class, and you have defined a discriminator column, then you can include "m.class" in your select, and it will include that column's value.  if you don't have a discriminator column, do.  otherwise how can you tell which rows from that table are which type?

Comment: Yeah, I discovered the discriminator after posting that comment so I edited it to reflect that.